# C++ function segfaults when using last variable from the signature

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have this JNI function that crashes (SIGSEGV 11) when we use the last variable passed to the function. As far as I can tell, there's nothing inherently wrong with it. My bandaid solution was to add a third variable name (example is down lower) and to not use that third one, at all. (some variable names were changed to protect the innocent)

```
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_example_core_lib_nativeJavaCall 
    (JNIEnv * env, jclass, jlong nativeInstance, jlongArray listItems) {
float* resultStorage1;
float* resultStorage2;
/// Do some unrelated things ...
std::vector<LibClass> listofLibClasses = initialzeList(); //Create list fine
int statusCode = MyLib::coreCall(*libClassInstance, listOfLibClasses, 
                                  resultStorage1, resultStorage2);
// Add resultStorage1/2 to a jFloat array to give back to Java 
return <AjfloatArray>;
}
```

And the coreCall, which is your garden-variety C++:

```
int coreCall(LibClass *libClassInstance, std::vector<LibClass> listOfLibClasses, 
      float *result1, float *result2) {
float 
.... run some calculations
int resultCode = doSomething();
(*result1) = localFloatVariable; //this works fine and doesn't crash
(*result2) = otherLocalFloatVariable; //This one segfaults consistently.
....
return resultCode;
}
```

The "fix" is like so, notice the extra variable passed to `coreCall`:

```
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_example_core_lib_nativeJavaCall 
    (JNIEnv * env, jclass, jlong nativeInstance, jlongArray listItems) {
float* resultStorage1;
float* resultStorage2;
float* paddingFullOfWat;
/// Do some unrelated things ...
std::vector<LibClass> listofLibClasses = initialzeList(); //Create list fine
int statusCode = MyLib::coreCall(*libClassInstance, listOfLibClasses, 
                                  resultStorage1, resultStorage2, paddingFullOfWat);
// Add resultStorage1/2 to a jFloat array to give back to Java 
return <AjfloatArray>;
}
// ** //
int coreCall(LibClass *libClassInstance, std::vector<LibClass> listOfLibClasses, float
     *result1, float *result2, float *padding) { //Notice the extra float 
.... run some calculations
int resultCode = doSomething();
(*result1) = localFloatVariable; //this works fine and doesn't crash
(*result2) = otherLocalFloatVariable; //now this works
....
return resultCode;
}
```

I've used debugging statements to narrow down the crash to `(*result2) = otherLocalFloatVariable;` in the original call. I have also tried passing the original variables in backwards, since they're both floats anyway, and it crashes whenever `result2` is used. I'm thinking a compiler/environment error? This code ran fine during testing on a macbook Pro, I'm compiling with a Dell machine running Unix and loading this onto an Android phone. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `result2` pointing to a vaild memory address, when dereferencing it: `(*result2)`? Try running your program with valgrind.

Comment: I've tried initialzing it in the first function, but I can't check to see if it contains anything because it crashes whenever I use it in any way. I can't use valgrind on Android.

Comment: How are `resultStorage1` and `resultStorage2` allocated?

Comment: My mistake, in my code they weren't named right when being declared. They are there now, they are being declared like `float *resultStorage2;`.

Comment: Can you include the code where resultStorage1/2 are being allocated? As the code sits right now, it appears you declare float*, but they are never allocated, which would certainly lead to a crash.

Comment: They weren't allocated, but that didn't stop only one of them from working while the other didn't. I set up the following in the nativeJavaCall: `float simplefloat = 0.0;  float* resultStorage1 = &simplefloat;` but it doesn't let me save anything into them in the `coreCall` function.